# Proving that $n \leq m^{2} \leq 2n$ by induction

Tags: induction

I am trying to prove that there exists a perfect square between a natural number and its double, and I am trying to prove it by induction. Here is my proof so far, but I am kind of stuck.

for $n=1$, choose $m=1$. For $n=2$, choose $m=2$.

I figured out that when $ m^2 \geq n+1$ then the the square overlaps between the range from $n$ to $2n$ and $n+1$ to $2(n+1)$.

So I need to prove it when $m^2=n$.

So $n\leq m^2$

$n+1 \leq m^2+1 \leq m^2 + 2m + 1 = (m+1)^2$

but now I can't prove that

$(m+1)^2 \leq 2n+2$

The furthest I got is trying to prove that

$ m^2 + 2m \leq 2n$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that when $m\ge 2$ and $m^2 = n$,

$$(m+1)^2 = m^2 + 2m + 1 \le 2m^2 +1 \le 2m^2 + 2 = 2n+2.$$

Comment: So you used the induction hypothesis to sub in m for 2?

Comment: If $m$ is not $\ge 2$, then $m=1$ and thus $n=1$. You can assume that it is checked already and start at $n=2$ for example. @Panphobia

Comment: I still don't understand how you got $m^2 + 2m +1 \leq 2m^2 +1$.

Comment: Use $2m \le (m)m$ as $m\ge 2$. @Panphobia